# Appsettings and middleware Core 2.1

Tags: middleware, asp.net-core-2.1, appsettings

I have made a custom middleware and now I want to access the appsettings that are in another project in my solution. Should I inject the IConfiguration object into the middleware constructor, and add the using statement of Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration? Or is there a better way to do this?

I am working with ASP.net Web page with Core 2.1.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
public class MyMiddleware
{
  public IConfiguration _configuration;
  public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IConfiguration config)
  {
     _next = next;
     _ configuration = config;
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't need all your configuration passed to your middleware but just a section you can use

```
IOptions<T>
```

Create MyConfig.cs Class file:

```
public class MyConfig
{
   public string MyConfig1 {get; set;}
   public string MyConfig2 {get; set;}
}
```

In ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<MyConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("MyConfig"));
}
```

In your middleware

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class MyMiddleware
    {
        private readonly IOptions<MyConfig> _appSettings;
        public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IOptions<MyConfig> config)
        {
            _next = next;
            _configuration = config;
        }

        public MyMethod()
        {
            _configuration.Value.MyConfig1
        }
    }
```

In appsettings.json file:

```
{
  "AppSettings": {
    "AppId": "0001",
    "AppName": "xxxx",
  },
  "MyConfig": {
    "MyConfig1": "xxxxxxx",
    "MyConfig2": "xxxxxxx",
  },
}
```